# Using asyncio and threading queues, how do I signal the workers to shutdown when the queue itself is being refed unknown times until finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, python-asyncio

Using Python 3.6 but can upgrade

I have this issue with both the asyncio and threading classes, and moving forward the problem description applies to both (the project requires both for reasons that are not important to the problem). The queue is fed a list of URLs that the workers then process, and based on the results it either feeds a handful of tasks back to the queue or if the results meet the requirements it posts the data to a database. Example code:

```
from threading import Lock, Thread
from queue import Queue
from selenium import webdriver
import random

MAX_WORKERS = 7

class DoStuff:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/' for _ in range(100)]
        self.resent = []
        self.process_fullfilled_num = 0

    def start(self):

        for _ in range(MAX_WORKERS):
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
            worker_thread = Thread(target=self.worker, args=(driver,))
            worker_thread.daemon = True
            worker_thread.start()

        for url in self.urls:
            grid = random.randint(1,1000000)
            self.queue.put({'url':url,'grid':grid})

        while True:
            with self.lock:
                _process_fullfilled_num = self.process_fullfilled_num
            if _process_fulfilled_num == len(self.urls)*2:
                self.queue.join()
                break

    def worker(self, driver):

        while True:

            task = self.queue.get()
            url = task['url']
            grid = task['grid']

            if task is None:
                # break ???

            driver.get(url)
            # To make sure the request worked
            _t = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('title').text

            if grid not in self.resent:

                self.resent.append(grid)
                self.queue.put({'url': url, 'grid': grid})

            else:

                # This is where I have problems
                self.queue.put(None)
                # or maybe...
                self.queue.put('some_signal')

            with self.lock:
                self.process_fullfilled_num += 1

            self.queue.task_done()
```

The problem with this code is that when the queue is populated everything works fine, but when the number of tasks are lower and the workers don't immediately have a task then how can I signal for the workers to wait and how do I signal when everything is done? The challenge is that the number of times the URLs need to be fed back into the queue will always be unknown and so sometimes the workers need to wait. There might be circumstances where one worker produces enough URLs after one or two tasks that put all the other workers back in the game. What I still don't know is how to finalize the workload for the program to perform its tear-down when all responses meet the requirements and make sure all tasks are complete.

For one attempt, I shut down the workers when `queue.qsize() == 0 and task == None` by feeding the queue with `self.queue.put(None)` but that causes a premature end or causes the workers to hang (I used a set number where the URLs are fed back in to the queue one time - 100 URLs should cause 200 requests but it always stops at about 160-180). So if there are a couple workers waiting on a response then it shuts down early or just hangs.

I have seen a number of other scenarios, but all the research I've done involves either the number of tasks are known and can therefore end or the processed responses don't need to be fed back into the queue (or the number of times they need to be fed back to the queue is known). But my issue is that the number of tasks from start to finish is unknown AND the number of times the new URLs need to be fed back to the queue is also unknown.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I also tried adding a second queue that processes the responses but to the same results.

EDIT 2: One of the issues I have is that I want to be sure that all the URLs are getting processed and I'm using the increment variables to print. So I don't know if the incrementing is hitting race conditions or if the URLs are not actually getting processed.

Comment: I don't quite get it, you already use `queue.task_done()`; can't you use `queue.join()` to wait until the workers are done processing their tasks (as well as the additional tasks), and only then enqueue `None` to tell them to quit? Can you provide a _runnable_ example that reproduces your issue, something with sleeps and prints?

Comment: @user4815162342 Just modified the code a bit so you can run it. I also added the `queue.join()` and getting the same result of missing a couple URLs based on print statements. If I understand your comment correctly, should I use `queue.put(None)` after `queue.join()` in the `while` loop in `start()`? My problem is that even with a lock on the `process_fullfilled_num` increment and when calling the var it sometimes doesn't hit the requirement of 200.

Comment: Why are the *workers* sending the kill signal? And at a time when they have no reason to believe the work is done.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica  That is just one of many solutions I tried. Whether the kill signal is in `start()` or anywhere else the problem of knowing when all the workers have no more tasks remains since the number of times the workers `put()` to the queue is never known. Almost like using `random.choice(['yes', 'no'])` for the worker to decide whether or not to send a task to the queue.

Comment: "the problem of knowing when all the workers have no more tasks remains" - that problem is what `join` solves.

Comment: This is true yet the program still gets stuck in an infinite loop from being short a URL or two.

Comment: To expand on the first comment: yes, your main thread needs to pre-fill the queue, then call `queue.join()`, and finally enqueue the `None` end-of-work sentinel. Individual workers should consist of a loop that performs the following: a) dequeue the resource, b) check for `None` and exit if detected, c) process the resource from the queue, possibly enqueuing additional resources, and d) call `queue.task_done()`. If that doesn't work for you, please show the code that implements that approach (mocking selenium with sleeps, so that we can run it) and reproduces the issues you are having.